# Android Studio 1.3 and C++ static libraries

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on generating a static C++ library to wrap with JNI use with Android. Using Visual Studio 2015's [new support for Android C++ libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cplusplus-mdd-vs.aspx), I was able to generate a *dynamic* library (`.so`), and pulled it into Android Studio. Once it was in the proper directory, it was able to link properly, and I was able to call a native method.

However, doing exactly the same thing, but generating a *static* library (`.a`), I continuously got `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, indicating the library was not found by the app. Everything else was controlled for (i.e. same build settings, same location of the library in the file system, etc).

Has anybody else tried doing this? Is there something special that needs to be done to get Android Studio to recognize `.a`s?

Comment: I've noticed something interesting... In implementing the function `JNI_OnLoad`, if I return `JNI_VERSION_1_6`, my dynamic library is loaded, but if I return 0x00010008 (which seems to be what corresponds to `JNI_VERSION_1_8`, although I'm not sure because my copy of jni.h doesn't define it) it is not.

According to [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNJI_OnLoad), returning anything lower than `JNI_VERSION_1_8` will not allow for static linking. But it seems like that version isn't supported in Visual Studio / Android Studio yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Android Studio just doesn't support Java 8 yet (and with it, support for linking static C++ libraries). So Microsoft is a little ahead of the game with their support for creating those static libraries. Guess it's dynamic linking for the time being.

[image]